# React Updating dependency of dependency

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, dependency-management

Is there a tricky way to update a dependency that one of my main dependencies depends on ? specifically, jquery version needs to be updated in my react-slick requirement.

Comment: can you give a code example of what atr you meaning?

Comment: @GuyCohen, What I mean, I have a dependency to react-slick. And react-slick has it's dependency to jquery^3.2.1. Obviously I have no control over this jquery dependency. Our security team does not accept this version of jquery and asked us to update it. But since we have no direct control over it, I am looking for a way to update only the jquery version.